# utf8 to utf8mb4 mysqli charset php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, character-encoding

I just converted my mysql database from utf8 to utf8mb4 so support Emojis, but now i have an encoding problem. If i print the text with php special characters are displayed normally, but they are saved as LATIN1 Ã¼ in the database

I followed this guide https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

In php i set the charset like this after establishing the connection

```
 mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8mb4");
```

before converting, ä was saved as ä, ö was saved as ö and so on.

now its : ü -> Ã¼ and so on, so the common utf8 encoding problem.

mysql version is 5.5.46 so that souldn't be the problem

```
 database is utf8mb4_unicode_ci
 tabels are utf8mb4_unicode_ci
 varchar and text columns are also utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that

```
  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8mb4");
```

changed the charset to LATIN1 instead of utf8mb4, but with

```
  $mysqli->query("set names utf8mb4");
```

it is working fine